# How to reference a property in microsoft bot framework

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I'm using Composer.
The text prompt is - What is your name? And I want to store the user input in a $name property.

In the User Input section - under property - the placeholder gives examples saying you can use $birthday or dialog.${user.name}.

When I use $name as the property I am unable to then get access to the property during the reply eg the reply is "Welcome ......"  - and the name is blank.
I have tried Welcome {$name} and Welcome ${name} without success.

But when I use user.name in the property field then I am able to access the property and replying "Welcome Jack" works.

Could I please get clarification on whether $name or $birthday can be used to store values.

Thx

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bot state handling is stateless, You have to specify the property with the state(memory) ex: user.Name, here the user is Bot user state(memory)

once you specify the state, your property and value get stored otherwise it's lost.

ex : user.name or user.birthday you get the values otherwise it's lost.

bot has different memory states user state, Conversation state, dialog state, etc.  For more information refer [Bot state management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

Comment: re: user input - my conversation is setup to recognise the user inputting "My name is ..." or "I am ....". The beginning of each of those is a capital letter. If the user types in "my name is ...." this is not recognised. But I can't add "my name is ...." to the list of user inputs because composer fails and says that there will now be two versions of the same input ie it considers "My name is...." and "my name is" to be the same. How do I handle both "My..." and "my...." if I can't add them to the list? Thanks

Comment: Are you using LUIS ?